# Model binder not working with JSON POST

Tags: c#, json, http-post, model-binding, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm sending the following JSON via a POST:

```
POST http://localhost:52873/news 

{"text":"testing","isPublic":true}
```

My controller:

```
public class NewsController : Controller
{
    // GET: /<controller>/
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post(CreatePostCommand command)
    {
        /* ...more code... */
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(200);
    }
}
```

And the command is:

```
public class CreatePostCommand
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool IsPublic { get; set; }
}
```

My route setup is the default which comes with the MVC template in VS 2014 CTP 4:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default", 
        template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "api",
        template: "{controller}/{id?}");
});
```

Quote from [Getting Started with ASP.NET MVC 6](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/overview):

> Using this route template, the action name maps to the HTTP verb in the request. For example, a GET request will invoke a method named Get, a PUT request will invoke a method named Put, and so forth. The {controller} variable still maps to the controller name.

This doesn't seem to work for me. I'm getting 404 error. What am I missing with this new ModelBinder? Why doesn't it bind my JSON POST message?

Comment: Add your script for the ajax method

Comment: Does the case matter in your JSON? So `text` should be `Text`?

Comment: Also what is your route setup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works after

- removing `[HttpPost]` attribute, and
- adding `[FromBody]` attribute before attribute type.

The corrected code:

```
// No HttPost attribute here!
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]CreatePostCommand command)
{
    /* ...more code... */
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(200);
}
```

Comment: Interesting, any idea why?

Comment: No idea. It's a question for the MS guys. However it's still in alpha4, so it can change until the final release.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have beta4 running and it still requires this.

Comment: I have `RC1` and still this occurs.